# XSLT / XPath getting the current node number

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following structure of xml data to transform:

```
 <root>
    <main1>
            <text-body>
                <title>A</title>
                <subtitle>A</subtitle>
            </text-body>
    <!-- other stuff -->
            <text-body>
                <titel>Aa</titel>
                <subtitel>Aa</subtitel>
            </text-body>
    <!-- other stuff -->
            <text-body>
                <titel>Aaa</titel>
                <subtitel>Aaa</subtitel>
            </text-body>
    </main1>
    <main2>
        <text-body>
            <title>B</title>
            <subtitle>B</subtitle>
            <body>B</body>
        </text-body>
        <text-body>
            <title>C</title>
            <subtitle>C</subtitle>
            <body>C</body>
        </text-body>
        <text-body>
            <title>D</title>
            <subtitle>D</subtitle>
            <body>D</body>
        </text-body>
    </main2>
    </root>
```

And I need to replace the data in main/text-body with the data in main2/text-body, but keep the other stuff in main1. The output should look like this:

```
<root>
        <main1>
              <text-body>
                <title>B</title>
                <subtitle>B</subtitle>
                <body>B</body>
                </text-body>
        <!-- other stuff -->
              <text-body>
                 <title>C</title>
                <subtitle>C</subtitle>
                <body>C</body>
              </text-body>
        <!-- other stuff -->
              <text-body>
                <title>D</title>
                <subtitle>D</subtitle>
                <body>D</body>
              </text-body>
        </main1>
        <main2>
            <text-body>
                <title>B</title>
                <subtitle>B</subtitle>
                <body>B</body>
            </text-body>
            <text-body>
                <title>C</title>
                <subtitle>C</subtitle>
                <body>C</body>
            </text-body>
            <text-body>
                <title>D</title>
                <subtitle>D</subtitle>
                <body>D</body>
            </text-body>
        </main2>
        </root>
```

I have the following xsl-code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="main1/text-body">
           <xsl:param name="count" select="count(preceding-sibling::node())"/>
           <xsl:copy-of select="/root/main2/text-body[$count]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I try to get the current node index of main1/text-body to fill in the right text-body of main2. But it doesn´t work. Here is the current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
        <main1>
              <text-body>
                <title>B</title>
                <subtitle>B</subtitle>
                <body>B</body>
            </text-body>
        <!-- other stuff -->

        <!-- other stuff -->

        </main1>
        <main2>
            <text-body>
                <title>B</title>
                <subtitle>B</subtitle>
                <body>B</body>
            </text-body>
            <text-body>
                <title>C</title>
                <subtitle>C</subtitle>
                <body>C</body>
            </text-body>
            <text-body>
                <title>D</title>
                <subtitle>D</subtitle>
                <body>D</body>
            </text-body>
        </main2>
        </root>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XPath and XSLT are 1-based indexes. In order to select the first item, your predicate filter would look for `[1]`, not `[0]`.

Given that, the variable `$count` needs to have `1` added to the `count()` of the preceding-sibling selection. Also, you should be counting the `text-body` elements that are preceding-siblings, not all/any `node()`

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="main1/text-body">
        <xsl:param name="count" select="count(preceding-sibling::text-body)+1"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/root/main2/text-body[$count]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```